# Directive, Link Function, Array, DataBinding Order of things is ambiguous

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, 2-way-object-databinding, angular-controller

I have a problem which is very challenging, that i don't even know how to define, so I'm going to give an example and hopefully you will be able to explain what am i doing wrong.
My HTML is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="object in Objects">
    <td>
        <div table-checkbox row-index="{{$index}}" bind-model="selectedChecks[$index]" selected-Checks="selectedChecks">

       </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The `selectedChecks` array is define the controller like this: `$scope.selectedChecks = {}`
and the result of the markup is a column of checkboxes
Here is my directive's code:

```
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        rowIndex: '@',
        selectedChecks: '=',
        bindModel: '='
    },
    template:'<input type="checkbox" ng-model="bindModel" ng-change="checkit(rowIndex)">',


    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
       scope.checkit = function(i){
           alert(scope.bindModel + " " + scope.selectedChecks[i]);
        };
    }
};
```

The problem is that when the first checkbox is checked the alert will output: "true undefined"
form the second check/uncheck of any checkbox from now and own the output will be: "true false" and "false true"

My expectation was that the two variables will be the same since they should have point to the same value since: 
`scope.bindModel` is sent to the directive from `selectedChecks[$index]` and `scope.selectedChecks[i]` should be the same.
Please help me understand what am i doing wrong here.
It seems that `checkIt` functions runs before Angular does the data-binding between the checkboxes and the array.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide us with plunker/jsfiddle. Or tell us what the data will be in `$scope.selectedChecks = {}`?.

Comment: Yes sure, it holds key value pare where the key is the current $index and the value is true or false as a result from the angular data bind from the checkbox

Comment: `ng-model="bindModel"` makes sure that every time a checkbox is checked it binds true or false to `$scope.selectedChecks[$index]`

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that checkIt functions runs before Angular does the
>   data-binding between the checkboxes and the array.

No, `checkIt` function is not running before Angular dose the data binding. The reason why you get `true undefined` at the first time you check the first one is that `$scope.selectedChecks = {}` is empty. That's mean there is no property like:

```
$scope.selectedChecks = {
    0: false
};
```

So, the time you check first checkbox, `ng-model="bindModel"` will update `$scope.selectedChecks = {}` like so:

```
$scope.selectedChecks = {
  0: true
}
```

And the same with other checkboxes.

Comment: I know that, the question was not why its undefined, it was why they didn't both were true? They should have pointed on the same variable at that point

Comment: `scope.bindModel` comes from `bind-model="selectedChecks[$index]"` in the directive's tag in the HTML. Which means it should have been pointed to `scope.selectedChecks[i]`

Comment: They are pointing to the same variable but the reason why they didn't both were true is when you check the first checkbox for example, `ng-change` will update the value for `ng-model`. Thus the value of `bindModel` will be true. And because you specified two-way binding, `bindModel` will try to update `selectedChecks` with the new value. But as I mentioned `selectedChecks` doesn't has `0: false` property for example, thus you will you get undefined when you call `selectedChecks[i]` for the first time. Here angular will create the property and assign the value so next time you get right output.

Comment: Thanks Ali, but as i mentioned i never get the right output, they are always opposite to each other

Comment: I think now, if you can create plunker/jsfiddle would be great to see your case in action.